# Why isn't my custom region showing up?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to create a new region called 'usermenu' for my theme in Zen. I've therefore added

```
region[usermenu] = User menu
```

to the `mytheme.info` file, added

```
<?php if ($logged_in): ?>
  <div id="usermenu">
    <div class="menu">
      <?php print render($page['usermenu']); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

to the `mytheme.tpl.php` file and added

```
#usermenu {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 35px;
}
```

to one of my CSS files. After clearing caches multiple times, the new region is displayed correctly and I can detect it with Firebug, but it doesn't show up in the block section.

What's going wrong and how can I solve this?

Comment: Make sure you're looking at the correct "Theme" tab in the blocks admin page.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Yes, I'm looking at the correct tab. When I hit "Demonstrate block regions (mytheme)", the 'usermenu' region isn't highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! It was just a stupid typo in the `.info` file. I should have inserted `regions[usermenu] = User menu`...